# se pueden pasar dos funciones a una sola vista en laravel?

Tags: laravel

estoy realizando una consulta en `laravel` pero quiero que me resuelvan esta pregunta, es posibles hacer dos funciones y luego retornarlas a la misma vista??, si se puede hacer me dicen como hacerlo por favor, dejare la vista y el controlador para que me puedan responder

```
@extends('template.plantilla')
@section('content') 
<title>Pedidos Concentrado | Cercafe</title>
<style type="text/css">
    a>strong{
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    a:hover{ 
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    div.modal-header{
        background: red; 
    }
    div.modal-header>h3{
        color: white;
    } 
</style> 
<div class="panel panel-default"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="token" required />
    <div class="panel-heading" id="titulo">
        <h4 style="font-size: 25px;"><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nuevos Pedidos</h4>
    </div>
    <br>
    @if(Auth::User()->rol_id == 9)
        <div class="container-fluid col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
            {!!Form::open(['route'=> 'admin.filterConcentradoPedidos.store', 'class'=>'form-inline', 'method'=>'POST'])!!} 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Desde:</label>
                    {!!Form::text('fecha_de',null, ['id' => 'date_picker_desde', 'class'=>'form-control', 'readonly', 'required', 'style' => 'cursor: pointer !important;'])!!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Hasta:</label>
                    {!!Form::text('fecha_hasta',null, ['id' => 'date_picker_hasta', 'class'=>'form-control', 'readonly', 'required', 'style' => 'cursor: pointer !important;'])!!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::select('granja', $granjas, array('0' => 'Seleccione una granja'), ['placeholder' => 'Selecciona una granja', 'class' => 'form-control col-xs-8' ]) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="tipo" id="tipo" class="form-control col-xs-8">
                        <option value=" ">Formato de Busqueda</option>
                        <option value="pd">Pedidos</option>
                        <option value="pr">Productos</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!!Form::submit('Buscar', array('class'=>'btn btn-success'))!!}
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            <div class="form-group pull-right"> 
                <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Regresar</a>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.entregaconcentrados.index')}}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock"> </i> Asignar Turno</a>
            </div> 
        </div>
    @endif 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        pedido = [];
        @foreach($pedidos as $pedido)
            var estado = {{$pedido->estado_id}};
            var consecutivo = {{$pedido->consecutivo}};
            item = {}
            item["estado"] = estado;
            item["consecutivo"] = consecutivo;
            pedido.push(item);  
        @endforeach
        pedido["pedido_concentrados"] = pedido;
    </script>
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive"> 
        <table id="data_list" class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
            <thead style="background-color: #df0101;">
                <tr style="color: white;">
                    <td><strong>Consecutivo</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Granja</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Fecha de Creación</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Fecha Estimada</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Estado</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Fecha de Entrega</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Conductor</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Vehiculo</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Documentacion</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                @if(Auth::User()->rol_id == 10)
                    @foreach($g_as as $g)
                        @if($g->user_id == Auth::User()->id)
                            @foreach($pedidos as $pedido)
                                @if($g->granja_id == $pedido->granja_id)
                                    @if($pedido->fecha_entrega == 'por verificar' || $pedido->conductor_asignado == 'por verificar' || $pedido->vehiculo_asignado == 'por verificar')
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            $(document).ready(function () 
                                            {
                                                $("#modificar_f_concentrados{{$pedido->id}}").datepicker(
                                                { 
                                                    changeMonth: true,
                                                    changeYear: true,
                                                    yearRange: "1950:2100",
                                                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
                                                    showButtonPanel: true,
                                                });
                                            })
                                            function enviarCampos(id)
                                            {
                                                var modificar = [];
                                                var consecutivo = id;
                                                var entrega = document.getElementById("modificar_f_concentrados{{$pedido->id}}").value;
                                                var conductor = document.getElementById("cd{{$pedido->id}}").value;
                                                var vehiculo = document.getElementById("vh{{$pedido->id}}").value;

                                                console.log(consecutivo + " " + entrega + " " + conductor + " " + vehiculo);

                                                item = {}
                                                item["cons"] = consecutivo;
                                                item["fecha"] = entrega;
                                                item["cond"] = conductor;
                                                item["placa"] = vehiculo;

                                                modificar.push(item); 

                                                modificar["modificar_concentrados"] = modificar;

                                                console.log(modificar);
                                                var token = $("#token").val(); 
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    type: "POST",
                                                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                                                    url: "http://201.236.212.130:82/intranetcercafe/public/admin/modificarPedidoC", 
                                                    dataType: 'json',
                                                    data: {data: JSON.stringify(modificar)}
                                                });
                                                swal({
                                                    title:'Pedido Modificado Satisfactoriamente.',
                                                    text:'',
                                                    type:'info',
                                                    showCancelButton:false,
                                                    confirmButtonClass:'btn-primary',
                                                    confirmButtonText:'Recargar'
                                                },
                                                function(isConfirm)
                                                {
                                                    if (isConfirm) 
                                                    {
                                                        location.reload();
                                                    }
                                                });   
                                            }
                                        </script>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="{{ route('admin.pedidoConcentrados.show', $pedido->consecutivo) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                                    <strong>PCO{{ $pedido->consecutivo }}</strong>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{ $pedido->nombre_granja }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $pedido->fecha_creacion }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $pedido->fecha_estimada }}</td>
                                            <td><strong style="color: #FDAE05;"> En Tramite </strong></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <strong>
                                                    <input id="modificar_f_concentrados{{$pedido->id}}" class="form-control" type="text" name="fecha" value="{{ $pedido->fecha_entrega }}" readonly />
                                                </strong>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="conductor" class="form-control" id="cd{{$pedido->id}}" selected="selected" />
                                                    @if($pedido->conductor_asignado == 'por verificar')
                                                        <option value="por verificar">{{ $pedido->conductor_asignado }}</option>
                                                        @foreach($conduct as $c)
                                                            <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->nombre}}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    @else
                                                        @foreach($conduct as $c)
                                                            @if($pedido->conductor_asignado == $c->nombre)
                                                                <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->nombre}}</option>
                                                            @endif
                                                        @endforeach
                                                        @foreach($conduct as $c)
                                                            <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->nombre}}</option>  
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    @endif
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="vehiculo" class="form-control" id="vh{{$pedido->id}}" selected="selected">
                                                    @if($pedido->vehiculo_asignado == 'por verificar')
                                                        <option value="por verificar">{{ $pedido->vehiculo_asignado }}</option>
                                                        @foreach($vehicul as $v)
                                                            <option value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->placa}}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    @else
                                                        @foreach($vehicul as $v)
                                                            @if($pedido->vehiculo_asignado == $v->placa)
                                                                <option value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->placa}}</option>
                                                            @endif
                                                        @endforeach
                                                        @foreach($vehicul as $v)
                                                            <option value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->placa}}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    @endif
                                                </select>  
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="validar" onclick="enviarCampos({{ $pedido->consecutivo }});"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Validar</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @elseif(Auth::User()->rol_id == 6)
                    @foreach($g_as as $g) 
                        @if($g->user_id == Auth::User()->id)
                            @foreach($pedidos as $pedido)
                                @if($pedido->estado_id == 2)
                                    @if($g->granja_id == $pedido->granja_id)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="{{ route('admin.pedidoConcentrados.show', $pedido->consecutivo) }}">
                                                    <strong>PCO{{ $pedido->consecutivo }}</strong>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{ $pedido->nombre_granja }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $pedido->fecha_creacion }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $pedido->fecha_estimada }}</td>
                                            <td><strong style="color: #8BC34A;"> Tramitado </strong></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <strong>
                                                    {{ $pedido->fecha_entrega }}
                                                </strong>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {{ $pedido->conductor_asignado }}</option>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {{ $pedido->vehiculo_asignado }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="/intranetcercafe/public/admin/excelPedidoConcentrados/{{$pedido->consecutivo}}" class="btn btn-success"><i>{!!Html::image('c.png','us',array('class' => 'imuser'))!!} </i></a>
                                                <a href="/intranetcercafe/public/admin/pdfPedidoConcentrados/{{$pedido->consecutivo}}" class="btn btn-danger"><i>{!!Html::image('pdf.png','us',array('class' => 'imuser'))!!} </i></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>   
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @elseif(Auth::User()->rol_id == 9)
                    @foreach($pedidos as $pedido)
                        @if($pedido->estado_id == 2)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.pedidoConcentrados.show', $pedido->consecutivo) }}">
                                        <strong>PCO{{ $pedido->consecutivo }}</strong>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ $pedido->nombre_granja }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $pedido->fecha_creacion }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $pedido->fecha_estimada }}</td>
                                <td><strong style="color: #8BC34A;"> Tramitado </strong></td>
                                <td>
                                    <strong>
                                        {{ $pedido->fecha_entrega }}
                                    </strong>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ $pedido->conductor_asignado }}</option>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ $pedido->vehiculo_asignado }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="/intranetcercafe/public/admin/excelPedidoConcentrados/{{$pedido->consecutivo}}" class="btn btn-success"><i>{!!Html::image('c.png','us',array('class' => 'imuser'))!!} </i></a>
                                    <a href="/intranetcercafe/public/admin/pdfPedidoConcentrados/{{$pedido->consecutivo}}" class="btn btn-danger"><i>{!!Html::image('pdf.png','us',array('class' => 'imuser'))!!} </i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </div>
</div>
@if(Auth::User()->rol_id == 10)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="titulo">
            <h4 style="font-size: 25px;"><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Historial</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <table id="data_list_estados" class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
                <thead style="background-color: #df0101;">
                    <tr style="color: white;">
                        <td><strong>Consecutivo</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Granja</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Estado</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Fecha de Entrega</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Conductor</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Vehiculo</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Documentacion</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    @foreach($g_as as $g)
                        @if($g->user_id == Auth::User()->id)
                            @foreach($pedidos as $pedido)
                                @if($g->granja_id == $pedido->granja_id)
                                    @if($pedido->estado_id  == 2)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="{{ route('admin.pedidoConcentrados.show', $pedido->consecutivo) }}">
                                                    <strong>PCO{{ $pedido->consecutivo }}</strong>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{ $pedido->nombre_granja }}</td>
                                            <td><strong style="color: #8BC34A;"> Tramitado </strong></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <strong>
                                                    {{ $pedido->fecha_entrega }}
                                                </strong>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {{ $pedido->conductor_asignado }}</option>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {{ $pedido->vehiculo_asignado }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="/intranetcercafe/public/admin/excelPedidoConcentrados/{{$pedido->consecutivo}}" class="btn btn-success"><i>{!!Html::image('c.png','us',array('class' => 'imuser'))!!} </i></a>
                                                <a href="/intranetcercafe/public/admin/pdfPedidoConcentrados/{{$pedido->consecutivo}}" class="btn btn-danger"><i>{!!Html::image('pdf.png','us',array('class' => 'imuser'))!!} </i></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
{{-- <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" id="titulo">
            <h4 style="font-size: 25px;"><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> PCO{{$consecutivo}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead> 
                        <tr style="color: white;">
                            <td><strong>Nombre de la Granja</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Nombre del Concentrado</strong></td>
                            <td><strong># Bultos</strong></td>
                            <td><strong># Kilos</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($productos_db as $producto_db)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$producto_db["granja"]}}</td>
                                <td>{{$producto_db["concentrado"]}}</td>
                                <td>{{$producto_db["bultos"]}}</td>
                                <td>{{$producto_db["kilos"]}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
--}}</div>
@endsection
```

este es el codigo del controlador, la funcion index hace que cargue los datos una vez se carga la pagina

```
public function index()
{
    $conduct = Conductor::all();
    $g_as = AsociacionGranja::all();
    $vehicul = VehiculoDespacho::all();
    $granjas = Granja::lists('nombre_granja', 'id');
    $conductores = Conductor::lists('nombre', 'id');
    $vehiculos = VehiculoDespacho::lists('placa', 'id');
    $pedidos_c = DB::table('consecutivos_concentrados') 
            ->join('granjas', 'consecutivos_concentrados.granja_id', '=', 'granjas.id')
            ->select('consecutivos_concentrados.*', 'granjas.nombre_granja')
            ->orderBy('consecutivo', "desc")
            ->get();
    return view('admin.pedidos.consultar_pedido_concentrados', compact('granjas', $granjas, 'conductores', $conductores, 'vehiculos', $vehiculos, 'conduct', $conduct, 'vehicul', $vehicul,'g_as',$g_as))->with('pedidos', $pedidos_c);  
}
```

mientras que esta funcion me carga el modal que esta comentado por que cuando se carga la pagina me genera un error diciendo que la variable consecutivo no estaba definida

```
public function show($consecutivo)
{
    $productos = PedidoConcentrado::all();
    $granjas = Granja::all();
    $concentrados = Concentrado::all();
    $seleccionados =  [];

    foreach ($productos as $producto) 
    {
        if ($producto->consecutivo_pedido == $consecutivo) 
        {
            foreach ($granjas as $granja) 
            {
               if ($granja->id == $producto->granja_id) 
               {
                   foreach ($concentrados as $concentrado) 
                   {
                        if($concentrado->id == $producto->concentrado_id)
                        {
                            $productos_db[$producto->id]["granja"] = $granja->nombre_granja;
                            $productos_db[$producto->id]["concentrado"] = $concentrado->nombre_concentrado;
                            $productos_db[$producto->id]["bultos"] = $producto->no_bultos;
                            $productos_db[$producto->id]["kilos"] = $producto->no_kilos;
                        }
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    } 
    if ( !empty($productos_db) && is_array($productos_db))
    {
        return view('admin.pedidos.consultar_pedido_concentrados', compact('consecutivo', $consecutivo))->with('productos_db', $productos_db);
    }
    else
    {
        flash('<strong>Ha Ocurrido un Error con este Pedido!!!</strong>')->error()->important();
        return redirect()->route('admin.pedidoConcentrados.index');
    }  
}
```

entonces mi pregunta es, se pueden enviar dos funciones a una misma vista????

Comment: creo que si se puede pasar mas de dos arreglos

Comment: Realmente veo un montón de código en esa vista, incluyendo una cantidad de if y foreach anidados que no permiten entender casi nada. La respuesta es sencilla: **SÍ** puedes llamar a una vista desde cuantos métodos quieras (asumiendo que eso es lo que estás preguntando).

Comment: y como podria mandar los dos arrays a la misma vista ??

Comment: ¿cuáles dos arrays?

Answer (score 0):

La verdad que tu código está dificil de leer y no entiendo muy bien lo que querés hacer. Fijate de optimizarlo porque te va a ayudar a vos mismo en el futuro.

***Comentario:***  Los foreach esos los podes eliminar agregando la relacion correspondiente a tu modelo de Producto.

**El modelo Producto**

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','no_bultos','no_kilos','concentrado_id','granja_id','consecutivo_pedido'
    ];

    public function concentrado()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Concentrado', 'concentrado_id');
    }
    public function granja()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Granja', 'granja_id');
    }
}
```

**En el controlador**

```
public function show($consecutivo)
{
    $producto = Producto::with(['concentrado', 'granja'])
                         ->where('consecutivo_pedido',$consecutivo)
                         ->first();
    return view('admin.pedidos.consultar_pedido_concentrados')
             ->with('productos_db', $producto);
    // En este caso por ejemplo para acceder al nombre de la granja 
    // en la vista tendrias que hacer 
    // $producto->granja->nombre_granja 
    // y lo mismo con concentrado
}
```

**Para responder tu pregunta:**

1- Dividí las vistas en base a los requerimientos que cada una necesite.
    (Ej. `listado_de_productos.blade.php` y `listados_de_granjas.blade.php`)

2- Creá un view composer para cada vista en el archivo **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** dentro del método `boot()` (También podés crear un Service Provider solo para los view composers).

```
public function boot() {
  /**
   * Este View Composer envía el listado de todos los productos
   * a la vista de listado de productos
   * en la variable $productos
   */
  view()->composer('listado_de_productos', function($view) {

    // Podés hacer la consulta que quieras yo usé all() para simplificar.
    $productos = \App\Producto::all(); 
    // También podés enviar datos estáticos 
    // $productos = ['producto1','producto2','producto3' ];

    $view->with('productos', $productos);
  });

  /**
   * Este View Composer envía el listado de todas las granjas
   * a la vista de listado de granjas
   * en la variable $granjas
   */
  view()->composer('listados_de_granjas', function($view) {
        $granjas = \App\Granja::all();   
        $view->with('granjas', $granjas);
  });

}
```

Mas info en este [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers)

En ese link vas a encontrar info mas detallada sobre las opciones que tenés disponibles.
Por ejemplo:

- Si la vista está es una subcarpeta funciona igual que en el controlador (usás puntos): `composer('subcarpeta.listado_de_productos', ...)`
- Si necesitás compartir información con varias vistas reemplazá el nombre de la vista por un array de nombres de vistas: `composer(['listado_de_productos', 'listado_de_granjas'], ...)`
- Si necesitás compartir información con todas las vistas colocá un `*`: `composer('*', ...)`

**Agregado en respuesta a tu comentario `y como podria mandar los dos arrays a la misma vista ?? – Juan Esteban Yarce el 24 abr. a las 21:20`**
**Para pasar 2 variables a una vista podés hacerlo de la siguiente maneja**

```
public function show($consecutivo)
{
    $productos = Producto::all();
    $granjas = Granja::all();
    return view('NOMBRE_DE_LA_VISTA')
             ->with('productos', $productos)
             ->with('granjas', $granjas);
}
```

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda,
saludos
Maru